# regex to include line breaks

Tags: php, regex

I have this simple text to parse through Regex:

```
T. Condesa:
(52) (555) 1111 2222T. Polanco:
(52) (55) 1111-2222T. San Ángel:
(52) (55) 1111-3333T. Paseo Arcos Bosques:
(52) (55) 2222-3333T. Antara:
(52) (55) 1111-1111T. Interlomas:
(52) (55) 1111-1111T. Prado Norte:
(52) (55) 1111 1111T. Reforma:
```

Now here I only want the First phone number -

```
T. Condesa:(52) (555) 1111 2222
```

how can we parse using PHP to inlcude line breaks ?

Comment: Just match `\s*` instead of `.` to match the newline behind the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input data is a bit weird, but you can rely on the fact that there are no T for your particular example and get the result you want with a simple:

```
/^T[^T]+/
```

This matches a `T` and as many non-`T` characters until the next `T`. And here's the code:

```
$str = 'T. Condesa:
        (52) (555) 1111 2222T. Polanco:
        (52) (55) 1111-2222T. San Ángel:
        (52) (55) 1111-3333T. Paseo Arcos Bosques:
        (52) (55) 2222-3333T. Antara:
        (52) (55) 1111-1111T. Interlomas:
        (52) (55) 1111-1111T. Prado Norte:
        (52) (55) 1111 1111T. Reforma:';
preg_match("/^T[^T]+/", $str, $res);
print_r($res[0]);
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/loaTT0).

Comment: thank you, meets the purpose well, however wouldnt it be a problem if the case is T. Texas: (00) (000) 0000 0000T.

Comment: @Cruising2hell In that case, you can try out `preg_match("/T\.(?:[^T][^.])+/", $str, $res);` see [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/sC4lP2). This is still a simple one, if you don't want to get a 'rigid' pattern which can be more suited but more complex as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

For PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) flavor (use by PHP's `preg_*` functions):

```
           /^([^:]+:)\n([ ()0-9-]+)/
            ^        ^^
            |     line-break
            |
  Begin of string anchor
```

Put the anchor on the beginning of the string and name the line-break explicitly (LF; `\n`).

This `\n` line-break is for unix specifically. So this must not be the line-break that is in your string. So to also support CRLF, LF and CR sequences (that is Dos, Unix and Mac) you can use

```
(?>\r\n|\n|\r)
```

There are even more and you can even configure the regex engine and then just use `\R` for a line-break. You find this outlined in detail in:

- [PCRE and newlines (Dec 2011; by NikiC)](http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/10/PCRE-and-newlines.html)

To use these regex in PHP you need to take care however and use single-quoted strings *otherwise* you must escape each `\` to not enter a line-break verbatim because in double quoted strings in PHP you really enter a line-break then [if you write `\n` (but not `\R`)](http://3v4l.org/HAvRT). So take a bit care of the quotes.

Example:

```
$subject = 'T. Condesa:
(52) (555) 1111 2222T. Polanco:
(52) (55) 1111-2222T. San Ángel:
(52) (55) 1111-3333T. Paseo Arcos Bosques:
(52) (55) 2222-3333T. Antara:
(52) (55) 1111-1111T. Interlomas:
(52) (55) 1111-1111T. Prado Norte:
(52) (55) 1111 1111T. Reforma:';

preg_match('/^([^:]+:)\R([ ()0-9-]+)/', $subject, $matches)
  && vprintf('%2$s %3$s', $matches); # prints 'T. Condesa: (52) (555) 1111 2222'
```

Comment: When matching a line break explicitly like this I would recommend always using `\r?\n` to support the varying newline formats

Comment: @SmokeyPHP: Then I'd suggest `(?>\r\n|\n|\r)` ;)

Comment: but that's just a long way of saying `\r?\n` ...

Comment: no, you won't match the single `\r` with your combo. Also the backtracking is different.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a new line use:

```
\s*
```

For example a very simple regex to match T. Condesa and the number below it:

```
T. Condesa:\s*\(52\) \(555\) 1111 2222
```

- `\s` is whitespace including:

  - `\r` is a carriage return
  - `\n` is a newline

To implement this in PHP use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: `\s` includes `\r` and `\n` so you can write only `\s*` instead. - see as well: http://www.php.net/regexp.reference.escape.php#112061

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm capturing the description of the phone number and the phone number as separate strings using [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). In the end we have an array that contains the phone numbers. The following shows how to capture any of the phone numbers and omit the line breaks.

```
<?php

$string = "T. Condesa:
(52) (555) 1111 2222T. Polanco:
(52) (55) 1111-2222T. San Ángel:
(52) (55) 1111-3333T. Paseo Arcos Bosques:
(52) (55) 2222-3333T. Antara:
(52) (55) 1111-1111T. Interlomas:
(52) (55) 1111-1111T. Prado Norte:
(52) (55) 1111 1111T. Reforma:";

$pattern = "!(T[^:]+):\s+([)(\s\d-]+\d{4})!";

preg_match_all($pattern,$string,$matches);

$Tel = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$desc){
  
  $Tel[$desc]=$matches[2][$key];
    
}

print_r($Tel);

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [T. Condesa] => (52) (555) 1111 2222
    [T. Polanco] => (52) (55) 1111-2222
    [T. San Ãngel] => (52) (55) 1111-3333
    [T. Paseo Arcos Bosques] => (52) (55) 2222-3333
    [T. Antara] => (52) (55) 1111-1111
    [T. Interlomas] => (52) (55) 1111-1111
    [T. Prado Norte] => (52) (55) 1111 1111
)
```

To get only the first record you would use:

```
 echo "T. Condesa:".$Tel['T. Condesa'];
```

**Output**

```
 T. Condesa:(52) (555) 1111 2222
```